# How to retain logs after pod deletion in AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, azure-aks

Is there any way to add configuration to my AKS cluster to keep log data from Kubernetes pods that have been deleted. For example, If there were 3 pods running, after sometime or maybe a day; there are only 2 pods. I would want to see logs of that terminated/ deleted pod.

Is there a way to configure some logging solution in AKS to store the logs of deleted pods for a period of time? Or If pod is going to be terminated it should save logs somewhere before termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  Azure Monitor to collect logs from your AKS cluster and store them in a `Log Analytics workspace`.
You can also query logs from `Container insights` in `Azure Monitor`. To access all data in the workspace, select `Logs` from the `Monitoring` menu and limit the data to your Kubernetes cluster, select Logs from that cluster's menu as below-

[image]
[image]

Another way is to run

```yaml
kubectl get event -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name -n <namespace> --no-headers
```

which will give you the list of terminated pods in your namespace and use
`kubectl logs -f yourpodname -n yournamespace -p`

```
kubectl get event -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name -n mysql --no-headers
dapr-sidecar-injector-dfb9d4bcb-ffmvl.179379eb6d5c4dc4
dapr-sidecar-injector-dfb9d4bcb-z5pfz.179379ebb57f3d99
dapr-sidecar-injector-dfb9d4bcb-z5pfz.179379ebd6a980b0
dapr-sidecar-injector-dfb9d4bcb-z5pfz.179379ebd7168124
dapr-sidecar-injector-dfb9d4bcb-z5pfz.179379ebd8f2f52b
dapr-sidecar-injector-dfb9d4bcb.179379ebb13ecdb3
```

Note, The above command to fetch terminated pod details will give you the pods which were terminated 1 hour ago
[image]
Reference Doc-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/monitor-aks by MS resource KarishmaTiwari

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007134/how-to-see-logs-of-terminated-pods)